# Failing to implement voting system with Asp.net MVC 5 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to basically have users "like" a post, which I call "voting" for a post in my application.

I have a vote class which records the userid, the postid (called a story), and the rest is boilerplate.

```
public class Vote
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string VoterId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Voter { get; set; }

        public int StoryId { get; set; }
        public Story Story { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

In the story model, I have a reference to a collection of votes which I theoretically will call a .Count() and print the number of "votes" to the view when it comes time to render the post details page.

```
public virtual ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
```

Inside the razor view, when a user is looking at a post(story), deciding whether or not to vote for it, I have this form. So if the user logged in isn't the author of the story, then they can vote for the story.

```
@if (!Model.IsStoryOwner)
            {
                <div class="row mt-1">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("New", "Vote"))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Story.Id, new { StoryId = Model.Story.Id })
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info voteBtn" id="LikeBtn">
                                    <i class="fa fa-heart mr-2"></i>
                                    Vote
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

This hits the following controller:

```
//POST /vote/new
        //FOR adding a vote to a story
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult New(Vote vote)
        {
            var voterId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            var newVote = new Vote
            {
                VoterId = voterId,
                StoryId = vote.StoryId,
                CreatedAt = DateTime.Now
            };

            dbContext.Votes.Add(newVote);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return View();

        }
```

however the storyId is coming through as null even though I've verified that it's not on the client-side when I run the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your current view code will generate the HTML markup for a hidden input element with **name** attribute value `Story.Id`.

```
<input name="Story.Id" type="hidden" value="1">
```

When the form is submitted, model binder will not be able to map the value of that input to `StoryId` property of `Vote` object. For model binder to properly map the values, the input element name should match with the property name of the class you are using as the parameter of your action method.

You can create a hidden input with the name attribute value matching to your property name

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("New", "Vote"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <input type="hidden" name="StoryId" value="@Model.Story.Id" />

    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info voteBtn" id="LikeBtn">
            <i class="fa fa-heart mr-2"></i>Vote
        </button>
    </div>
}
```

Or you can use the `Html.Hidden` helper method which generates the same markup as above.

```
@Html.Hidden("StoryId",Model.Story.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `HiddenFor` the `Story.Id`, not `StoryId`.

If your `Model` contains a value for `StoryId`, you can simply use

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.StoryId)
```